# Why button battery LR1154 is called LR44?

Tags: batteries

It seems I cannot find complete explanation for this question everywhere on the internet.

So far, I know the followings:

- L - Alkaline as +/Zinc as -
- R - round
- 11 - battery's diameter in mm (in fact, the standard states, that the actual diameter is 11.6 mm<sub>[[1]](http://www.pickvacuumcleaner.com/lr44-ag13-l1154-button-cell-battery.html)</sub>)
- 54 - battery's height in 0.1 mm

What's the meaning of 44?

Comment: The wonderful thing about standards is just how many of them we have to choose from.

Comment: @ScottSeidman, what's the logic behind that naming? I cannot believe it is randomly chosen.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR44_battery

Comment: @ScottSeidman, I've read that article, unfortunately I didn't find an answer there. It doesn't explain what is the meaning of 44 in a right way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LR44 is some companies proprietary name for the IEC LR1144 battery.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_battery_sizes

> Manufacturers may assign proprietary names and numbers to their
>   batteries, disregarding common, colloquial, IEC, and ANSI naming
>   conventions (see LR44 battery as an example). Often this is done to
>   steer customers towards a specific brand, and away from competing or
>   generic brands, by obfuscating the common name.

The table in the middle of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_battery_sizes#Silver_oxide_and_alkaline_cells shows that the LR1144 IEC designation corresponds to the "most common" name of SR44, otherwise called the LR44

Comment: Thank you for the help in finding the truth on this noisy internet

Answer (score 3):

Look on Wikipedia:

"The battery nomenclature is defined by the International Electrotechnical Commission (IEC) in its 60086-3 standard (Primary batteries, part 3 Watch batteries). The letter "L" indicates the electrochemical system used: a zinc negative electrode, manganese dioxide depolarizer and positive electrode, and an alkaline electrolyte. "R44" indicates a cylindrical ("round") cell 11.4±0.2 mm diameter and 5.2±0.2 mm height."

[LR44 Battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR44_battery)

Comment: I went through that article, I cannot find any connections between R44 and "11.4±0.2 mm diameter and 5.2±0.2 mm height."